# i got error the name 'model' does not exist in current content

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I can use @model in cshtml in views folder bu i want to use this another folder for login operation.

I create a cshtml file in Account folder.But i cant use @model.I got error like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the class that will be used as the model for this view, ie.

`@model MyApp.Web.Models.ViewModels.AccountModel`

If you don't need a strongly-typed model in this view just delete `@model` declaration.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/19/asp-net-mvc-3-new-model-directive-support-in-razor.aspx